# How to destruct object in reducer (REACT)

Tags: reactjs, object, redux, react-redux, reducers

I have the following userData in state

```
userData : {
 isValidCheckup: true,
 accounts: {
  userAccount: [
    {
      accountType: 'checkings',
      includeInCheckup: false
    },
    {
      accountType: 'checkings',
      includeInCheckup: false
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, I have a reducer to handle manipulation of above data. Note: I only want to update `includeInCheckup` field. Depending on the `accountType` recieved as a payload to the reducer.

Here is the reducer function I am using

```
case UPDATE_USER_DATA: {
  const { field, value } = action.payload; // field='checkings', value=true
  return {
   ...state,
   userData: {
     ...state.userData
   }
  }

}
```

As you can see, I am getting `field='checkings', value=true` from the payload to the reducer. How can I specifically update this value to the `includeInCheckup` property based on the field value.

Can someone please shed some light.

Comment: How do you identify which element in `userData.accounts.userAccount` array you want to update? Or do you simply want to update all of them?

Comment: @DrewReese- based on the field value i get in payload.

Comment: Right. Ok. In your sample data you have two identical elements, i.e. with the same `accountType` and `includeInCheckup` values. My question is how do you determine which element in the array to update, or do you want to update all elements with a matching `accountType` property?

Comment: @DrewReese- When i get field as 'checkings', i update the first element of array 'userAccount' and when i get field as 'savings, i will update the second element of array. This is hardcoded and fixed

Comment: If you only have one entry for each type of account, I would suggest using an object keyed by type rather than an array.

Comment: @DrewReese- i understood your solution. I have put a comment over there. Can you please clarify my doubt based on the updated question. It would be of great help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I get field as 'checkings', I update the first element of array
> 'userAccount' and when I get field as 'savings, I will update the
> second element of array.

For example state, I am assuming `userAccount[0]` is a checking account type, and `userAccount[1]` is a savings account type, and the array will always be length 2.

```
userData : {
 isValidCheckup: true,
 accounts: {
  userAccount: [
    {
      accountType: 'checkings',
      includeInCheckup: false
    },
    {
      accountType: 'savings',
      includeInCheckup: false
    }
  ]
}
```

Copy each level of state that is being updated, and then update the property by creating a new object/array reference. You can simply map the `userAccount` array and check if the account type matches that of the action payload field, and update the `includeInCheckup` property.

```
case UPDATE_USER_DATA: {
  const { field, value } = action.payload; // field='checkings', value=true
  return {
    ...state,
    userData: {
      ...state.userData,
      accounts: {
        ...state.userData.accounts,
        userAccount: state.userData.accounts.map((account) =>
          account.accountType === field
            ? {
                ...account,
                includeInCheckup: value
              }
            : account
        )
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Resse- If i dont have accountType as a field, your solution code which has account.accountType === field wont exist. How would you map the value and update it to includeInCheckUp property in that case ?

Comment: @RaviK You said the array was hardcoded to include two elements, one each of "checkings" and "savings". Is your `UPDATE_USER_DATA` supposed to add user data as well? I guess I don't quite understand your data and use case (sorry if it is just me that is confused). The pattern for this is to first search the array if the element exists with the property/value you want to update, if it exists then you map as I've suggested, otherwise you still copy the data and append new element object.